# Автодеплой с github.com на свой ftp

Tags: git, html, php, github

Хотелось бы выработать примерно следующую схему.

Имеется несколько проектов: промо-сайт - статический html, тема для wordpress - несколько php файлов. Несколько разработчиков кодят на локальных машинах. Проекты под контролем git. Репозиторий хранится на github. "боевая версия" лежит на хостинге, доступ через ftp.

Хочется, что бы при push`е на github происходила автоматическая выкатка на хостинг.

Пробовал делать по [этой статье](http://writing.markchristian.org/2011/03/10/how-to-deploy-your-code-from-github-automatically.html). Не работает и не понятно, как оно вообще должно работать, ведь нигде не указываются параметры ftp. Попробовал codeship.io, аналогично. Читаю статью на [гит-хелп](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks). Начиная с раздела **The payload** все туманно.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что вот эти вот Post-Receive хуки являются своего рода триггерами событий, при помощи которых можно отследить, что прошел push, а дальше надо вызвать какой-то скрипт, который осуществит отправку файлов на ftp?

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда дальше копать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, тригерры, это такой механизм улучшения. Они срабатывают в определенных ситуациях и могут даже немного управлять процессом. К примеру, можно сделать триггер, который будет срабатывать перед коммитом и проверять орфографию (скрипт проверки орфографии нужно будет написать самостоятельно). Если проверка показала ошибки, то коммит можно отклонить с скрипта.

В той инструкции делается следующее. Когда происходит push, то сервер github'а дергает скрипт. Этот скрипт с одной строки Вы располагаете у себя на сервере. А состоит он с одной команды - сделать `git pull`. Поэтому там и нет никаких ftp паролей. В этом способе есть только одна особенность - git должен быть на сервере. Но скорее всего он там есть.

Comment: Спасибо. Судя по всему на серверу нету гита. Хостинг Руцентр, тариф самый дешевый. Пробовал зайти по ftp через консоль far`а и выполнить git -v. Ушел читать про установку гита. Затем вернусь к этому сценарию. Маленькие вопрос: этот скрипт должен лежать в корневом каталоге репозитория, рядом с папкой .git? Правильно `git pull` или 'git pull'?

Comment: этот скрипт должен лежать в корне. А он сам создаст каталог `.git`. (этот каталог неплохо как-нибудь защитить, к примеру с помощью правил для апача, что бы  туда не лазили, кому не нужно).

и да, нужно писать с обратными кавычками, этот такой синтаксис. Он заставляет указанный код исполниться.